# osmar package in R (OpenStreetMap)

Tags: r, openstreetmap, osmar

The `osmar` package in R has a demo file called `demo("navigator")`.  It is provided to illustrate package capabilities and functions.  When I ten the script, I hit the following line and error:

```
R> muc <- get_osm(muc_bbox, src)
sh: osmosis: command not found
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '/var/folders/81/4k487q0969q1d8rfd1pyhyr40000gs/T//RtmpdgZSOy/file13a473cb904c': No such file or directory
```

The command is intended to convert an `osmosis` data object to a `osmar` object.  I have properly installed osmosis for MacOSX, updated my path definition in the bash shell to point to the osmosis executable.

I'm not sure what the error message means and how best to respond.  Any help appreciated
Brad

Answer (score 1):

Have your restarted R? It looks like osmosis isn't in your path, although you do mention that you set that. Make sure that you can run one of the osmosis commands in Terminal:

```
osmosis  --read-xml SloveniaGarmin.osm --tee 4 --bounding-box left=15 top=46 --write-xml SloveniaGarminSE.osm --bounding-box left=15 bottom=46 --write-xml SloveniaGarminNE.osm --bounding-box right=15 top=46 --write-xml SloveniaGarminSW.osm --bounding-box right=15 bottom=46 --write-xml SloveniaGarminNW.osm
```

The example is irrelevant, as long as it doesn't say `osmosis` file not found.

Also, make sure you have `gzip` in your path. I am almost certain that it is default, but the `demo` package relies on it to run. Just open a Terminal and type `gzip` to make sure it is there.

Finally, if you need to debug this, then run this:

```
library(osmar)
download.file("http://osmar.r-forge.r-project.org/muenchen.osm.gz","muenchen.osm.gz")
system("gzip -d muenchen.osm.gz")
# At this point, check the directory listed by getwd(). It should contain muenchen.osm.
src <- osmsource_osmosis(file = "muenchen.osm",osmosis = "osmosis")
muc_bbox <- center_bbox(11.575278, 48.137222, 3000, 3000)
debug(osmar:::get_osm_data.osmosis)
get_osm(muc_bbox, src)
# Press Enter till you get to
# request <- osm_request(source, what, destination)
# Then type request to get the command it is sending.
```

After you type Enter once, and then `request` you will get the string it is sending to your OS. It should be something like:

```
osmosis --read-xml enableDateParsing=no file=muenchen.osm --bounding-box top=48.1507120588903 left=11.5551240885889 bottom=48.1237319411097 right=11.5954319114111 --write-xml file=<your path>
```

Try pasting this into your Terminal. It should work from any directory.

Oh, and type `undebug(osmar:::get_osm_data.osmosis)` to stop debugging. Type `Q` to exit the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I just got this thing working. The problem is not with the system path variable for osmosis. It is with the system call the script makes which uses the "gzip" application to unzip the .gz file it has downloaded before. So there is an error when gzip is not installed in your machine or gzip is not in the system path variable. so installing gzip and adding it to the path variable will mitigate this error. alternatively you can unzip the file manually to the same path and run the script again.